# Can't get either Postgres permissions or PVC working in AKS

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

These are pretty much the steps I have followed in order. Basically what is outlined in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv

1. `azure-storage-claim.yaml`

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-app-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
  - cache=none
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
  location: westus
```

2. `azure-storage.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-app-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: test-app-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
```

PVC is now setup.

Changed the mountPath per the Postgres image documentation:

> PGDATA
>
> This optional variable can be used to define another location - like a subdirectory - for the database files. The default is /var/lib/postgresql/data, but if the data volume you're using is a filesystem mountpoint (like with GCE persistent disks), Postgres initdb recommends a subdirectory (for example /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ) be created to contain the data.
>
> This is an environment variable that is not Docker specific. Because the variable is used by the postgres server binary (see the PostgreSQL docs), the entrypoint script takes it into account.

Based on that, I have my `postgres.yaml` setup like the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env: 
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGDATABASE
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGUSER
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGPASSWORD
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql-data
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-app-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql-data
              subPath: postgres-storage
      volumes:
        - name: test-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-app-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: postgres
  ports:
    - port: 1423
      targetPort: 5432
```

You get the error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql-data': Operation not permitted
```

So with either of that as the Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine
EXPOSE 5432
RUN /bin/bash -c 'chmod 777 /var/lib/postgresql-data'
```

Or

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine
EXPOSE 5432
```

It doesn't really matter, you still get the same type of error by doing any the following:

```
            ...
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-app-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql-data
              subPath: postgres-storage
      volumes:
        - name: test-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-app-storage
     ...
```

Results in the following error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres". This user must also own the server process.
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8". The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql-data" exists but is not empty If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty the directory "/var/lib/postgresql-data" or run initdb with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql-data".
```

Try this:

```
            ...
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-app-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql-data
              subPath: postgres-storage
      volumes:
        - name: test-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-app-storage
     ...
```

And it results in this:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql-data': Operation not permitted
```

Try this:

```
            ...
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
              value: "-D /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-app-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
              subPath: postgres-storage
      volumes:
        - name: test-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-app-storage
     ...
```

And it results in this:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres". This user must also own the server process.
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8". The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8". The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata": Operation not permitted fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ...

So nothing seems to work that I've tried and following the documentation where I can.
```

Someone suggested to get rid of the volume mounts like so:

```
            ...
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      volumes:
        - name: test-app-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-app-storage
     ...
```

Which, hey, that actually works! But doesn't persist data given it just uses the Pod storage so is pretty pointless:

[image]

And sure enough when you create a table in Postgres, destroy the Pod, and then redeploy it, of course the table is no longer there.

So more than likely I'm doing something wrong, but I've been following the documentation and seems like this should work.

Where are things going wrong?

**EDIT: Permissions in Pod**

Apparently it is a permissions issue that occurs when `PGDATA` is the same directory as `mountPath`. For example:

```
  ...
  - name: PGDATA
    value: /var/lib/postgresql-data
volumeMounts:
  - name: test-app-storage
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql-data
    subPath: postgres-storage
...

or

  ...
  # if PGDATA is not specified it defaults to /var/lib/postgresql/data
  # - name: PGDATA
  #   value: /var/lib/postgresql-data
volumeMounts:
  - name: test-app-storage
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    subPath: postgres-storage
...
```

Something like this where they do not match will create the Pod, but uses Pod storage which I obviously don't want:

```
  # Thus /var/lib/postgresql/data
  # - name: PGDATA
  #   value: /var/lib/postgresql-data
volumeMounts:
  - name: test-app-storage
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql-data
    subPath: postgres-storage
```

Permissions `ls -l` looks like this:

```
$ ls -l

drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Feb  2 06:06 apt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Feb  2 06:07 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Feb  2 06:06 exim4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug 28  2018 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Nov 10 12:17 misc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Jan 30 00:00 pam
drwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 4096 Feb  2 06:07 postgresql
drwxrwxrwx 2     1000     1000    0 Jan 31 21:46 postgresql-data
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 Jan 30 00:00 systemd
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Feb  2 06:07 ucf

$ ls -l postgresql && ls -l postgresql/data && ls -l postgresql-data
total 4
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Feb  5 23:28 data
total 124
drwx------ 6 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 base
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:29 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_commit_ts
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_dynshmem
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  4281 Feb  5 23:28 pg_hba.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  1636 Feb  5 23:28 pg_ident.conf
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:33 pg_logical
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_multixact
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_notify
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_replslot
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_serial
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_snapshots
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_stat
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:51 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_twophase
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres     3 Feb  5 23:28 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_wal
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb  5 23:28 pg_xact
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    88 Feb  5 23:28 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 26588 Feb  5 23:28 postgresql.conf
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    36 Feb  5 23:28 postmaster.opts
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    94 Feb  5 23:28 postmaster.pid
total 0
```

The permissions for where it creates the data files is `postgres`. However, doing this, it doesn't map to Azure Files and the PVC. It just stays and is destroyed with the Pod.

I think what is happening is `mountPath` uses `root` and `PGDATA` uses `postgres`, and somehow `mountPath` is trying to use `postgres`???

Really, not sure and still lost as to how to resolve it.

**EDIT2**

Came across this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203031/3123109

So added the following to mine:

```
- name: postgres
  image: postgres
  command: 
  - /bin/chown
  - -R
  - "1000"
  - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But this generates a new error:

```
The selected container has not logged any messages yet.
```

Progress, I guess.

Comment: @JavierGuzmán I ended up using Azure Disks in the end. Could never get Azure Files working with PostgreSQL. That being said, I haven't tried it since I got it working with Azure Disks about a year ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to use Azure Disks instead. Maybe this has been fixed and you can use Azure Files since the beginning of 2020, but I haven't tried since getting this working with Azure Disks.

My `.yaml` configs look like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: file-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: default
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 25Gi
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres

    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env: 
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-prod-secrets
                  key: PGDATABASE
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-prod-secrets
                  key: PGUSER
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-prod-secrets
                  key: PGPASSWORD
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS
              value: "-A md5"
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/postgresql/data
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/postgresql
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: postgres
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

Comment: Neat :) 
I have been googling around for hours after this, even tried calling MS and Azure a couple of times with no luck, thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be due to the fact that you are trying to use a subPath as part of your deployment object

Please retry your first configuration without this line:

subPath: postgres-storage

It should result into this
volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

Let me know if that helps.

UPDATE: The docker image for the postgresql requires special attention when using persistent storage

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

The main caveat to note is that postgres doesn't care what UID it runs as (as long as the owner of /var/lib/postgresql/data matches), but initdb does care (and needs the user to exist in /etc/passwd):

The three easiest ways to get around this:

1. use the Debian variants (not the Alpine variants) and thus allow the image to use the nss_wrapper library to "fake" /etc/passwd contents for you (see docker-library/postgres#448 for more details)
2. bind-mount /etc/passwd read-only from the host (if the UID you desire is a valid user on your host):

$ docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "jsmith"

3. Initialize the target directory separately from the final runtime (with a chown in between):

$ docker volume create pgdata
$ docker run -it --rm -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
( once it's finished initializing successfully and is waiting for connections, stop it )
$ docker run -it --rm -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data bash chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/postgresql/data
$ docker run -it --rm --user 1000:1000 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-01-20 00:03:23 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

One solution would be to leverage the helm chart made by bitnami, they have worked out the default of the complex persistent storage configurations using an init container, and they also support the /dev/shm configuration needed to fix

Also note that the default /dev/shm size for containers is 64MB. If the shared memory is exhausted you will encounter ERROR: could not resize shared memory segment . . . : No space left on device. You will want to pass --shm-size=256MB for example to docker run, or alternatively in docker-compose

Here's the example of the init container used by the chart.

https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/postgresql/templates/statefulset.yaml#L74-L115

The recommendation would be to use helm to install the Postgres chart (which uses a statefuset) instead of trying to deploy the DB using a deployment object. (normally you want to use deployment objects for stateless application).

Comment: Now it just says: `
chmod: /var/lib/postgresql-data: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: I am using the bitnami one and when using helm chart with storageclass as azurefile it shows me similar error `chmod: changing permissions of '/bitnami/postgresql/data': Operation not permitted`

Comment: I have had several issues with this and as mentioned in the I answer above changing the storage-class will fix the problem. The accessMode `ReadWriteOnce` also makes sense in terms of dealing with a singular pod.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can use azure-disk, but not azure-file is because azure-file is based on the SMB protocol while azure-disk is not [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction)].

As andyzhangx on GitHub.com stated [[2](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/1494#issuecomment-505909474)]:

> SMB mount options (including dir permission) could not be changed, it's by SMB proto design, while for disk (ext4, xfs) dir permission could be changed after mount

Maybe also the approach used in [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318657/4278102)] would be a solution, but I will also stick to azure-disk for my (Bitnami) Postgresql PVC's for now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer all your question . I've made postgres pod work using PVC claim in AKS

1. Copy the docker & docker-entrypoint.sh file from https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/5c0e796bb660f0ae42ae8bf084470f13417b8d63/12/buster the reason I say so is we need to modify the uid & gid matching to the one defined in deployment.yaml as shown below. Here Im using 1025 .
   securityContext:
   runAsNonRoot: false
   runAsUser: 1025
   fsGroup: 1025
2. Change the 2 lines in the docker file

   groupadd -r postgres --gid=1025; 
   useradd -r -g postgres --uid=1025--home-dir=/var/lib/postgresql --shell=/bin/bash postgres; \
3. Then add an additional command in docker file after -> COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

4. Create the base image and push to azure container registry
5. deployment.yaml & storage.yaml below

apiVersion: apps/v1

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kinetic-postgres-alpha
  namespace: chatbot-dev
  annotations:
    buildNumber: 2020.04.15.1
    contributors: "Rakesh Sekar"
    azure-project: "Process"
    azure-repository: "IT-Robotics-Chatbot_Common"
    cmdb-app-name: "Robotics Chatbot"  # 
    docs: https://wiki.prodapt.com/
    description: |
      Chatbot Postgres Deployment
  labels:
    svc: kinetic-postgres-alpha
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      svc: kinetic-postgres-alpha
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        svc: kinetic-postgres-alpha
      annotations:
        buildNumber: 2020.04.15.1
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 10
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: svc
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - kinetic-postgres-alpha       
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"   
      containers:
      - name: kinetic-postgres-alpha
        image: winacr01.azurecr.io/robotics/chatbot_botpress_postgres_baseimage:12
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 750m
            memory: 1024Mi
        env:
        - name: TZ
          value: UTC       
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: botpress
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: appadmin
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: Admin4Chatbot
        - name: spring_profiles_active
          value: dev
        - name: APP_NAME
          value: kinetic-postgres-alpha
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: SERVICE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
            subPath: pgdata
            name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kinetic-postgres-pvc
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: false
        runAsUser: 1025
        fsGroup: 1025
      nodeSelector:
        agentpool: robotics
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kinetic-postgres-pvc
  namespace: chatbot-dev
  labels:
    svc: kinetic-postgres-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: managed-premium-retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

8. Why it works when to change the uid & gid of postgres to match the deployment.yaml you are running the AKS kubernetes pod as postgres user itself.

This avoids error such as :

chmod: changing permissions of 'var/lib/postgresql/data': Permission denied

chmod: changing permissions of 'var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Permission denied

9. Why the Persistent volume wont work if you use the default pgdata /var/lib/postgresql/data its gets mounted as pod storage to make this work define custom pgdata and mount as below

   ```
    - name: PGDATA
      value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    - name: NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: SERVICE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        subPath: pgdata
        name: postgredb
   ```

Its taken me 2 weeks to figure this out hope it helps everyone out there who tried like me .