# Can I access an Azure file share with non root user?

Tags: azure, permissions, chown, azure-files, chgrp

In this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files, it says that:

- Azure file share volume mount requires the Linux container run as root .
- Azure File share volume mounts are limited to CIFS support.

I have an azure container instance with postgres and postgres doesn't allow me to run the server as root.
The Azure file share owner is set to root and the user group also set to root and I will not be able to change both the permissions and the owner and the user group of the azure file share folder?
I would want to set the owner and group of the folder to postgres for example and change its permissions.

Comment: I’m not sure that I fully understood your question. Could you please try to rephrase your questions?
The points that you highlighted from the ACI documentation are valid. To mount the Azure File share on the client, you will need to run mount with as superuser i.e. as root user, or an user who has sudo rights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permissions on Azure File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58301985/permissions-on-azure-file)

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT That means in Microsoft Azure App Service we must let our containers use the root user to be able to use file share within our applications... Isn't that risky from a security point of view ? What if some attacker manages to have remote execution shell or command injection ? Of course you'll say that we have to code securely but...